Babel is NOT working well with the super keyword
I have this package.json:
{
  "name": "theme1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "lodashcustom": "lodash -o ./resources/libs/lodash/lodash.js include=debounce,filter,forEach,template,throttle"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.19.0",
    "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-cachebust": "^0.0.11",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^4.3.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-cssnano": "^2.1.3",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^7.0.1",
    "gulp-inline-source": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-rtlcss": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^5.1.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.5",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "glider-js": "^1.7.9",
    "gulp": "^5.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "sass": "1.77.6"
  }
}

and this is my gulp file:
var gulp = require('gulp'); 
var concat = require('gulp-concat'); 
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');

gulp.task('js', function(){
  return gulp.src([
      'resources/js/scroller.js',
      /* start alterative for resources\libs\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.bundle.js */
      /* popper is needed for BS dropdown.js */
      'resources/libs/popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.js',
      /* dom scripts and base-component are included for using BS components when needed  */
      'resources/libs/bootstrap/dist/js/dom/data.js',
      'resources/libs/bootstrap/dist/js/dom/selector-engine.js',
      'resources/libs/bootstrap/dist/js/dom/event-handler.js',
      'resources/libs/bootstrap/dist/js/dom/manipulator.js',
      'resources/libs/bootstrap/dist/js/base-component.js',
      /* include a BS component */
      'resources/libs/bootstrap/dist/js/dropdown.js',
      /* end alternative for bootstrap.bundle.js */
      'resources/libs/lodash/lodash.js',
      'resources/js/mobilenav.js',
      'resources/js/pixieLib.js',
      'resources/js/helpers.js',
      //'resources/js/animate-lazyload.js',
      'resources/js/image-lazyload.js',
      'resources/js/site.js'
    ])
    .pipe(concat('main.js'))
    .pipe(babel({
      'presets' : ['@babel/preset-env']
    }))
    .pipe(uglify()) // minify
    .pipe(gulp.dest('resources/assets/js'));
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('js'));

In my browser it returns the error:
main.67f2891f.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function
    at _inherits (main.67f2891f.js:1:3062)
    at main.67f2891f.js:1:34116
    at main.67f2891f.js:1:35224
    at main.67f2891f.js:1:33818
    at main.67f2891f.js:1:33861

It starts bugging me about the BaseCompononent class of Bootstrap( the link for BaseCompononent on Github).
The function super() is a keyword documented here
Am I missing something here? I have found a list of plugins here: https://babeljs.io/docs/v8-migration
{
  "presets" : ["@babel/preset-env"],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-private-methods"
  ]
}

